# Access 2007 referential integrity without using lookup within table

Tags: ms-access, lookup-tables

I've seen various posts here about not using lookup within a table. If you don't, how do you enforce referential integrity between a field and the allowable values from a lookup table? I can't create a relationship between the table field and the field in the lookup table because I can't create a unique (no duplicates) index on the field - the particular value needs to appear multiple times across the records in the table. But if I use the field properties to set a lookup on it and specify the field from the lookup table that it must contain, then this ensures that data can't be entered into this field that isn't in the lookup table.

Or have I got completely the wrong end of the stick here?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you always create forms for editing records. And in those forms you can create combo boxes that perform the lookups in the correct table and field. There are options there so that you can limit the data entry to only those values which are stored in the table. This option is called Limit To List (you'll see it in the combo properties).

Another important way to enforce that data exists in your lookup table is through your Relationships.

```
tblProducts
  ProductID (primary key)
  CategoryID (foreign key)
  ProductDescription

tblCategories
  CategoryID (primary key)
  Category
```

In the relationships window you would define a relationship between the two tables above on the CategoryID field. You are accomplishing several things here. It's more efficient to store only the CategoryID in your Products Table since you will be storing less data. Also, this way if you change the name on the category all records will reflect that change immediately. Every place that you display a product with its category you will need to create a combo box so that you display the Category Description as opposed to displaying the CategoryID.

As a side note, I recommend that you rarely use the Value List option as the Row Source Type in a combo. Using the Table/Query option and then creating an appropriate lookup table is a much more robust and flexible design.

Comment: Thanks but I did mention that I can't create a relationship as the field isn't unique. Whilst users of the form will be limited to the combobox items, this only applies to data entered via the form. Before it gets to the user I need to upload data from various sources, and unless the restriction is on the field in the table rather than just on the form control, then incorrect data can be stored.

Comment: You most certainly can create a relationship without the field being unique. Primary Keys/Indexes are the only things that enforce uniqueness.

Comment: Well when I tried to I got an error message that the relationship couldn't be created because the field in the primary table didn't have a unique index on it

Comment: So some of your tables don't have any primary key defined?

Comment: Yes, they each have a primary key, but in the case I've mentioned the field which needed a lookup value isn't a key. But even if I have the field set for lookup and limited to list, loading data with an APPEND statement still allows data to be stored which violates referential integrity.